# cant figure out why i keep getting com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream

Tags: java, mongodb, tomcat

Trying to figure out why I keep getting the exception ill show below.

This is my code:

```
CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry(), fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build()));
MongoClientOptions.Builder options_builder = new MongoClientOptions.Builder();
options_builder.maxConnectionIdleTime(60000);
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb+srv://USERNAME:MYPASSWORD@database-yyc55.mongodb.net/test\n", options_builder);
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
database = database.withCodecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry);
MongoCollection<AppUser> collection = database.getCollection("users", AppUser.class);
AppUser appUser = null;
String userName = null;
appUser = collection.find().first();
userName = facebook.getName();
```

as you can see I have done some research and tried setting maxIdleConnection to 60000 ms, yet still, I keep getting this exception.
the strange thing - this code worked before, and after one day of not using the database, it started happening.

Exception:

> com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
>       at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:87)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:547)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:418)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:290)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:255)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:84)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:34)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:91)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:51)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:114)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the problem was that my IP has changed, and on the server, I did not allow access to any other IP.
it solved it, yet I can't explain why i got the: "com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream" exception.
I also added option builder to my code, as you can see in the question above.